# Write an equation into Javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I need an equation that give the earth tilt of the current day. Max Tilt is 23.45 on 22 of June, min is -23.45 on 22 December.
I've found this equation which should works but I can't write it into javascript.

```
δ=sin-1(sin(23.45°)sin(360365(d-81)))
```

d is the number of the day (1-365). Source : http://pveducation.org/pvcdrom/properties-of-sunlight/declination-angle

My try :

```
Math.pow(Math.sin(Math.sin(23.45) * (Math.sin((360/365) * (356 - 81)))), -1)
```

which gives -1.3140077301935487, whereas -23.45 is expected.

Any ideas what's wrong on my conversion ?

Comment: You need to use radians.

Comment: I've tried radians to, it gives a bad result to : Math.sin(Math.sin(23.45 * (Math.PI/180)) * (Math.sin((360/365) * (356 - 81)))).  I've added the link to the source to see the equation with a valid format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, `Math.sin` [takes radians as arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin). So you will need to alter your equation to use radians.

Also, [Javascript has a method for arcsin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/asin): `Math.asin`:

Based on the equation from your source, the new result might look like:

```
var result = Math.asin(Math.sin(0.40927971) *
             Math.sin(0.0172142063 * ( (d - 81) * (Math.Pi/180) )));
```

Answer (score 2):

`Math.sin` takes radians as arguments. Here is how you convert degrees to radians :

```
radians = degrees * ( Math.Pi / 180 );
```

Comment: Yep, thanks. But the result is still wrong. Math.pow(Math.sin(Math.sin(23.45 * (Math.PI/180)) * (Math.sin((360/365) * (356 - 81)))), -1)  gives 2.945.